# Cannot get succes_url to be configured correctly for django

Tags: django, primary-key

**views.py**

```
class SongDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Song
    success_url=reverse_lazy("music:detail", song)
```

**models.py**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
    #return details of the album page we just created with the primary key

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + " - " + self.artist
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    song_file = models.FileField(null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.album_id})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

**urls:**

```
url(r'(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/song/delete/$', views.SongDelete.as_view(), name='song-delete'),
```

Problem:
I want to redirect to the details view music/ after deleting a song from the page. I can redirect to the index page but having problems redirecting to the details of the album page which has a primary key. I am sure it's the reverse_lazy function in the success_url which needs to be fixed. Any suggestions?